# Tizen TV - how to launch the app on the emulator?

Tags: tizen, tizen-studio, tizen-tv

I'm using the latest version of Tizen Studio and all of the development tools. When I try to launch my app on an emulator, it starts, but there is no sign of the presence of the application - just an empty system.
The "simulator" works properly, but it's just a browser, and I need to test some custom APIs. What should i do?
And if I try to drop the ready .wgt file into the emulator, it gives me a strange error: "closed"

Comment: I had all sorts of issues getting my app to launch on the emulator and TV itself.   I do recall seeing that same vague "closed" response when running in the emulator but can't for the life of me remember what caused it.   If you havent already, check out the forums https://developer.samsung.com/forum/en under the smart TV section.    I'll get back to you if I can remember how I resolved the "closed" issue.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered what the issue was.  In your project directory there should be a file called `.tproject`.   In that file ensure the `<name>` node's value is `tv-samsung-5.0` or `tv-samsung-4.0` depending on your tizen target.   If the value is just `tv-5.0` or `tv-4.0` you'll get the vague closed error.

Comment: Still the same error :(
Tried "tv-samsung-5.0" and "tv-samsung-4.0"